# Can't open Manifest editor with Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.android, android-manifest

I use to program with Eclipse and I'm starting with Xamarin in Visual Studio. The problem is that when I try to edit the Manifest it gets opened with the plain text editor:

[image]

But, when I'm following any tutorial, the Manifest gets opened this way:

[image]

What can I do to open the manifest with the Manifest like the second image?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What can I do to open the manifest with the Manifest like the second image?

The screenshot you posted shows the App's properties editor. You can open it through: "right click your project->properties->AndroidManifest".